# Running several instances of a docker container in a thread safe manner

Tags: docker, stdthread

I'm trying to run multiple instances of a linux executable on macOS via a docker container. The problem I face is that when I run multiple instances of the container, I/O to macOS is seriously slow. I suspect it is because of the way I run multiple instances of the container. How could I resolve this?

Details:

I have a centos-7 docker container to run a linux executable on macOS. The Docker file is:

```
FROM scratch
ADD centos-7-x86_64-docker.tar.xz /

LABEL \
    org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0" \
    org.label-schema.name="CentOS Base Image" \
    org.label-schema.vendor="CentOS" \
    org.label-schema.license="GPLv2" \
    org.label-schema.build-date="20200504" \
    org.opencontainers.image.title="CentOS Base Image" \
    org.opencontainers.image.vendor="CentOS" \
    org.opencontainers.image.licenses="GPL-2.0-only" \
    org.opencontainers.image.created="2020-05-04 00:00:00+01:00"

ADD my_exec_folder /usr/local/my_exec_folder
RUN yum install -y openssl
RUN yum install -y neon
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
COPY ./run_my_exec.sh /
RUN chmod +x /run_my_exec.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/run_my_exec.sh"]
```

My run_my_exec.sh runs as so:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                          

export MYEXEC="/usr/local/my_exec_folder/bin/my_exec"

cd $1
cp $MYEXEC .
./my_exec $2
rm ./my_exec
```

I build the container with:

```
docker build -t my_exec_c .
```

And then, in my program I run the container in a bash terminal opened with std::thread. The command I run the container with is:

```
docker run -t -v /my/rundir_id/on/macos:/rundir_id my_exec_c rundir my_inputs
```

, where rundir_id is like rundir_thread0, rundir_thread1 etc.

Comment: I would suspect that the main restraining factor, here, is disk I/O. Do they _need_ to share that rundir?

Comment: @Fildor Updated the question, they don't share rundir.

Comment: That `-v` option [is known to be slow](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/#known-issues).  The Linux and MacOS (BSD) environments are similar in many ways, and you might have more success recompiling the binary for native MacOS.

Comment: The executable is compiled and maintained by an external vendor who is not very keen on generating macOS binary...